# Accessing Server 2008 R2 manual shutdown notes and event logs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, event-log

When I manually reboot a server I am required to specify a reason for the restart and given the opportunity to provide a comment. How do I review my past shutdown reasons and comments and what is the best way to get rid of them? Is there a command to delete all previous such data? This is a test server and I have no interest re-reading my past mistakes.

I read that the Server 2012 shell is very capable, but I am still a beginner at using Windows Server and I plan to continue learning Server 2008 for a while longer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's prompting you for a comment when shutting down Windows is called the *Windows Shutdown Tracker*.  The reason code and comment you provide are written to the System event log with event ID `1074` with the source `USER32`.

You cannot clear individual events from Windows Event logs.  Instead, your only option is to clear the *entire* event log.  To do so:

1. Open Event Viewer
2. In the left pane select the log you want to clear (e.g. System)
3. In the right pane click **Clear Log...**
4. Optionally, Save the log, then click **Clear** to clear it.

Comment: I am looking for Windows Shutdown Tracker in Event Viewer.. no sign of it where is it? Is it under Windows Logs or Applications and Service Logs?

Comment: Got it.. under Windows Logs, System, USER32, Event ID 1074... Now how do I clear this, and all the other Events, I would like to have a fresh start...

Comment: Yes, Clear Log, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks!